# HOw to create a PrimeNg horizontal bar chart from right to left

Tags: angular, charts, angular-material, primeng

I'm trying to create a horizontal bar chart using PrimeNg which renders chart left to right by default.
Is there any way to make the chart renders from right to left??

My Options for the chart is

```
options = {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label(tooltipItem, data) {
          const tooltipValue =
            data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
          return parseInt(tooltipValue, 10).toLocaleString();
        },
      },
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 100,
      },
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
      position: 'top',
      onClick: (e) => e.stopPropagation(),
      labels: {
        fontColor: '#777777',
      },
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          display: false,
          stacked: false,
          gridLines: {
            display: false,
          },
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: false,
          },
        },
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          display: true,
          barThickness: '22',
          stacked: true,
          scaleLabel: {
            display: false,
          },
          gridLines: {
            display: false,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: {
      limitCenterText: false,
      datalabels: {
        display: true,
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'end',
        formatter(value) {
          return parseInt(value, 10).toLocaleString();
        },
        color: '#777777',
        font: {
          weight: 500,
          family: 'Roboto',
          size: 12,
        },
      },
    },
  };
```

The Stackblitz url for this is https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-chart-sanbox-d5ztmv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Is there any way to achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

This problem is almost certainly solved for OP but in case you came here:

```
options = {
  indexAxis: 'y',
  <<remainder of options>>
}
```

Should resolve OP's problem. The indexAxis controls which orientation the chart has, so changing that axis... changes the orientation